# Prove that solution set of $sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$ can not have exactly 10 Allegra

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Let $s,t,r$ be non-zero complex numbers and $L$ be the set of solutions $z=x+iy \, (x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ of the equation $sz+t\bar{z}+r=0$. Then prove that if $L$ can not have exactly 10 elements.

I calculated $z=\dfrac{t\bar{r}-r\bar{s}}{\mid{s}{\mid}^2-\mid{t}{\mid}^2}$. But how to proceed further?

Comment: Do you mean $sz+t\bar{z}+r = 0$?

Comment: If you can find an explicit expression for $z$ then there's only one solution (to whatever the equation is.)

Comment: A question just in time for allergy season

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I appreciate. Too few humor in Math SE...

Comment: Are you sure your question doesn't deal with **Gauss integers** $s,t,r$ (whose real and imaginary parts are integers) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to compute anything.

If the equation has more than one solutions, say $z_1$ and $z_2$, then any linear combination of $z_1$ and $z_2$ of the form $\lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a solution.

This means your equation has either $0, 1$ or infinitely many solutions. 
It is impossible for it to have exactly $10$ solutions.

Comment: How did you drive that $\lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda) z_2$ will be other solution?

Comment: @Zenix $$\begin{align}  & s(\lambda z_1  + (1-\lambda)z_2) + t (\overline{\lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2}) + r\\
\color{blue}{\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \to}\;\; = &s(\lambda z_1  + (1-\lambda)z_2) + t (\lambda \bar{z}_1 + (1-\lambda)\bar{z}_2) + (\lambda + (1-\lambda))r\\
= &\lambda(s z_1 + t\bar{z}_1 + r) + (1-\lambda)(s z_2 + t\bar{z}_2 + r)\\
= &\lambda(0) + (1-\lambda)(0)\\
= & 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: My question was how did you derive/think that *this* will be the other solution....

Comment: $s z + t \bar{z} + r = 0$ is an affine subset of the complex plane. if it contains two points, it contains all affine linear combination of those two points.

Answer (score 1):

From the given, we have

$$sz+t\bar{z}=-r, \>\>\> \bar s \bar z+\bar t {z}=-\bar r\implies
(|s|^2 -|t^2|)z = \bar rt-r\bar s$$

Two cases to consider:

1) If $|s|^2 \ne |t^2|$, there is a unique solution $z = \frac{\bar rt-r\bar s}{|s|^2 -|t^2|}$.

2) If $|s|^2 =|t^2|$, no solutions exist for $\bar rt\ne r\bar s$; or, infinite number of solutions for $\bar rt=r\bar s$.

Thus, the set can not have exactly 10 elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you write out your equation in terms of the real and imaginary parts of all the complex numbers involved ($s,t,r,z$) and then use the fact that a complex number (like $sz+t\bar z+r$) is $0$ if and only if both its real part and its imaginary part are $0$, you'll get two  **linear** equations for the two unknowns $x$ and $y$. So you can apply the theorem from linear algebra that a system of linear equations (over the real numbers) has either no solutions or a single solution, or infinitely many solutions. In particular, it can't have exactly $10$ solutions.